# X-editable not sending Json on submit()

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, x-editable

I have a problem using x-editable to create a new object en post it to my spring backend. At the moment I have my page to edit all the information. But when i hit the send button the information isn't send by in a json format but like this

```
id=value&id=value
```

I need to receive json because I will be using jackson to load the created object directly into my java object.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="row">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="record">
            <tr>
                <td>Traject name</td>
                <td><a class="myeditable" id="new_name" data-type="text">Name here</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Academic Year</td>
                <td><a class="myeditable" id="new_year" data-type="text">Year picker</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Courses</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="myeditable myCourse" id="courseName1" data-type="select"
                data-title="Select Course" >Courses</a></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Courses 2</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="myeditable myCourse" id="courseName2" data-type="select"
                data-title="Select Course" >Courses</a></td>    
            </tr>
        </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-btn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>&nbsp;Submit
    </button>
```

And the corresponding jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
 $('#new_name').editable(
         {name: 'trajectName',
             ajaxOptions: {
                    dataType: 'json'
                }}, 
         'validate', function(v) {
     if(!v) return 'Required field!';
 });

 $('#new_year').editable(
         {name: 'academicYear',
             ajaxOptions: {
                    dataType: 'json'
                }},
         'validate', function(v) {
                 if(!v) return 'Required field!';
 });


 $('.myeditable').editable({
        source: 'api/course/all/formated',
        sourceCache: true
    });  

 $('#save-btn').click(function() {
       $('.myeditable').editable('submit', { 
           url: 'api/traject/new',
           params: function(params) {return JSON.stringify(params);
            },
           ajaxOptions: {
               contentType: 'application/json',
               dataType: 'json' //assuming json response
            },
            success: function () {console.log("Success Respnse from server")},
            error: function() {console.log("Error response form server")}
       });
    });
});
```

The class witch will be filled with the json:

```
public class Traject {

private int id;

private String trajectName;

private int startingYear;

private List<Courses> courses;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Timbo925

Comment: I have the same problem. the params option only seems to work when it is attached to a field and the field update is sent individually. When sending all data with the submit event it isn't called.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for your question is in [this](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/106) issue.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#username').editable({
    ajaxOptions: {contentType: 'application/json', dataType: 'json'},
    params: function(params) { return JSON.stringify(params); },
  });
});
```

This works for me.